# Is it possible that Convert.ToBase64String returns a string with an ENTER?

Tags: .net, string, base64

I create an "encrypted" e-mail verification link using .NET's Convert.ToBase64String. Seldomly, I get informed that the link is splited, as if the new srting had new lines in it. Is that possible? Most likely it's just an e-mail client problem, but I wanted to be sure...

Comment: Post your code here, looks like you are not explicitly adding line breaks? Also what version of .NET is that?

Comment: I assume you already know it since you used the phrase "encrypted" but to be on the safe side.. ToBase64 is just as good as plain text, anyone can dump it into one of a million Base64Decode websites and get the plain text back very quickly. Consider using a hashing protocol (SHA-1) signed with a seeded pre-known salt value for checking authenticity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is possible - if you pass it `Base64FormattingOptions.InsertLineBreaks`, you will get a line break every 76 characters.

By default, there should be no line breaks, though.

Answer (score 3):

Insertion of line breaks is controlled by the second parameter of this overload:

```
public static string ToBase64String(
    byte[] inArray
,   Base64FormattingOptions options
)
```

If you pass `Base64FormattingOptions.InsertLineBreaks`, you get line breaks; otherwise, you do not get line breaks.

Single-parameter overload does not insert breaks.

Answer (score 2):

For dealing with URL's it's advisable to use `HttpServerUtility.UrlTokenEncode` instead.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpserverutility.urltokenencode.aspx

There are some known problems with using Convert.ToBase64String for URLs.

http://tipsforcdevelopers.blogspot.co.uk/2009/05/difference-between-converttobase64strin.html